# To make a recursive function with challenging constraints

Tags: python, function, recursion

I would like to make a function with an input string (for example 'abcdef'), and returns it in reverse order 'fedcba'.

However, the challenge is that the function

- must use a **recursive function**
- is without using for-loop
- is without any operators
- is without list slicing

This is my attempt which does not work:

```
def reverse(s: str) -> str
    if len(s) == 0:
       return None

    return
```

How do I use the recursive function here to reverse order? I tried to think of it but i'm new to recursive calls

Comment: `return s[-1] + reverse(s[:-1])`. You need to return empty sting instead of `None` in the if though.

Comment: @matszwecja OP doesn't want to use any slicing.

Comment: @matszwecja Doesn't want to use **any** operators either

Comment: @Stuart then OP shouldn't write code.

Comment: What kind of question is this? This belongs on Codewars, not SO.

Answer (score 3):

*"without using for loops or any operators or list slicing"* seems like a weird requirement, but the following function will do:

```py
>>> def reverse(s):
...     head, *tail = s
...     if tail:
...         return f'{reverse(tail)}{head}'
...     else:
...         return head
... 
>>> reverse('abcdef')
'fedcba'
```

In the scope of [lexical analysis](https://docs.python.org/3/reference/lexical_analysis.html#operators), `*` is regarded as an operator, so we can replace `head, *tail = s` with the following:

```py
import re

def reverse(s):
    head, tail = re.split('(?!^)', s, maxsplit=1)
    [...]
```

Or, alternatively:

```py
def reverse(s):
    __, head, tail = s.partition(next(iter(s))
    [...]
```

Or, yet another alternative:

```py
def reverse(s):
    s = iter(s)
    head, tail = next(s), ''.join(s)
    [...]
```

Comment: Isn't *=* an operator?

Comment: `=` is a name binding, the walrus operator `:=` would be an operator.

Comment: The glossary has the following to say about the [term "expression"](https://docs.python.org/3/glossary.html#term-expression): *"[...] an expression is an accumulation of expression elements like literals, names, attribute access, __operators__ or function calls which all return a value."* (emphasis mine) `x = y` is a statement that binds the name `x` to the value `y` and it doesn't return anything. So it's *not* an operator. That's the whole reason why they created the [walrus operator](https://peps.python.org/pep-0572/) (`:=`).

Comment: "Note: If the object is a class instance and the attribute reference occurs on both sides of the **assignment operator**" from: https://docs.python.org/3/reference/simple_stmts.html

Comment: As an addendum, the technical term for a construct like `x = y` is [assignment statement](https://docs.python.org/3/reference/simple_stmts.html#assignment-statements). In analogy to that there are [assignment expressions](https://docs.python.org/3/reference/expressions.html#assignment-expressions) of the form `x := y` which contain the `:=` operator.

Comment: `*` is an operator.

Comment: @philosofool The token `*` serves many purposes in the Python language, and in different contexts it has different meanings. `head, *tail = s` is an assignment statement and `*` does not function as an operator here. Other contexts where it doesn't function as an operator are `def f(*, x): ...` or `[*x]`.

Comment: @philosofool.  Pedantically, `*` in this case is an iterable unpacking operator, and `**` is the dictionary unpacking operator.  https://peps.python.org/pep-0448/.

Comment: @a_guest You are wrong, it is still an operator in all of those cases. Hell, even comma is an operator in your code.

Comment: I see that the various documents on Python language specification use the word "operator" for different constructs of the language. I don't know of any resource that precisely defines the term "operator" (it's not part of the glossary). To me, an operator (together with its operands), evaluates to some value and thus can be used as part of an expression (as written in the glossary for "expression"). Different tokens, e.g. `/*,`, can be used in different contexts and they have different meanings but they are not always operators. In `def f(x, /): ...` would you say `/` and `,` are operators?

Comment: I agree that the operator restriction needs to be more precisely defined.  As is, we could actually get around the restriction on using `+` by using `import operator` `operator.add(a, b)`, which technically doesn't use any 'operators' (unless someone wants to claim `,` as an operator.

Comment: As I see it, the problem is that the word "operator" can have different meanings in different contexts. For example in the scope of lexical analysis, `*` is an [operator](https://docs.python.org/3/reference/lexical_analysis.html#operators) while `=` and `,` are [delimiters](https://docs.python.org/3/reference/lexical_analysis.html#delimiters). Hence, the usage of "assignment operator" in the paragraph about [assignment statemtens](https://docs.python.org/3/reference/simple_stmts.html#assignment-statements) might be unfortunate. But in `def f(*, x): ...` I don't see `*` as an operator either.

Comment: According to the docs about lexical analysis, even `.` is a delimiter (not an operator). But inside the standard library we have [operator.attrgetter](https://docs.python.org/3/library/operator.html#operator.attrgetter) which serves the purpose of dotted attribute access (e.g. `x.y`). Also in the list about [operator precedence](https://docs.python.org/3/reference/expressions.html#operator-precedence), attribute reference (`x.y`) is mentioned. Hence, I conclude, that whenever the word "operator" is used, it should be accompanied by its context, either lexical analysis or expressions.

Comment: Another quote from [lexical analysis: delimiters](https://docs.python.org/3/reference/lexical_analysis.html#delimiters): [...] The second half of the list, the augmented assignment operators, serve lexically as delimiters, but also perform an operation.

Answer (score 2):

Edit: I have removed the '+' operator, and also the `lstrip()` which does not work on repeated characters in the string (thanks @philosofool)

Here's one way to do it without list slicing. And to clarify `s[0]` is list indexing not list slicing, correct?

```
def reverse(s):
    if len(s)==1:
        return s
    else:
        s1 = list(s)
        del s1[0]
        return ''.join([reverse(''.join(s1)), s[0]])
    
reverse('abccdefg')
```

output is

```
'gfedccba'
```

Comment: Strip removes every instance of the string in question, so this won't work on strings with repeat characters. If applied to  `missing` the result is missing an `s`.

Comment: hey this answer is brilliant, why the negative vote?!

Comment: @perpetualstudent There's a match operator.

Comment: @Ecin Yes, `[0]` is indexing, not slicing.

Answer (score 1):

This is not actually a solution. It meets all the requirements except the recursive one. It's a nice, purely functional solution, but not what OP asked for. Leaving it up in case anyone is interested....

```
from functools import reduce

def reverse_string(string):
    return reduce(lambda x, y: f'{y}{x}', string)
```

Comment: nice but it's not recursive :D

Comment: @Axeltherabbit What is the definition of a "recursive function"? If it only requires that the function refers to itself, you could add `if False: reverse_string(string)` to make it recursive.

Comment: I'd argue that an impossible branch doesn't count

Comment: @Axeltherabbit Duh. Thanks. Leaving it up anyway.

Comment: @Axeltherabbit How would you define "impossible" then? Is `len(string) >= 10**1000` impossible (it does contain an operator though)? Also, you could use `def reverse_string(string, n=1): if n: return reverse_string(string, 0); ...`. That actually performs one level of recursion.

Comment: I'd argue that an useless branch doesn't count either

Answer (score -1):

Using only functions

```
def reverse(strng, pos):
    if pos:
         next_pos = map(lambda x: x, range(pos,0,-1))
         next(next_pos) # skip first
         return ''.join((strng[pos],reverse(strng, next(next_pos)))
         
    else:
        return strng[pos]
```

Another one inspired by @Ecin

```
def reverse(strng : str):
   def inner(strng : list):
      return ''.join((strng.pop(), inner(strng) if strng else ''))
   return inner(list(strng))
```

Comment: `==` and `-1` both violate the "no operators" specification

Comment: This is very convoluted.

Comment: @nigh_anxiety right removed those now, I wonder if I can do something like next() to range

Comment: @OneMadGypsy yh I mean like the requirement

Comment: The original answer isn't convoluted AND it follows ALL of the requirements. Really anybody still trying to answer this question is wasting their time. The best possible answer has already been posted AND this question is one vote away from being closed.

Comment: You have to know that this answer has gotten worse with every change you've made. Look at the successful answer. Given the choice would YOU use your way?

Comment: Would you use codegolfing code irl? the other answer uses assignments and unpacking

Comment: It's your rep points. You already lost a couple answering a stupid question. Do as you will.

Comment: @OneMadGypsy It doesn't follow all the requirements. It is nearly impossible to follow them and write functional code.

Comment: Lol, it most certainly isn't best possible answer. Either we completely ignore the stupid requirement of "no operators" and make the code more sensible than what is here or we don't ignore it at all and the question has no answer.